# i can't type in text box which is run on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, event-handling

when i run my code it doesn't give me err ad run successfully, but i can't type anything in my text box. however i check if there is console err "
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
the err is at code line 14  [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8xhJ.png)
setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });

the problem is i cant type in textbox.

## addcandidate.js

```
import axios from "../axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
function Addcandidate() {
 

    const [data, setData] = useState({ candidate_name: "", imageURL: "",party_name: "" });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const handleChange = ({ Target: input }) => {
      setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
    };
  

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/addcandidate";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data);
            window.location = "/";
        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                setError(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };


   
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Logo>
        <img src="./amazon_logo.png" alt="" />
      </Logo>

      <FormContainer >
        <h3>Add Candidate</h3>

        <InputContainer>
          <p>candidate_name</p>
          <input
            // type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.candidate_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>ImageURL</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.imageURL}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>party_name</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.party_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        {/* <InputContainer>
          <p>Rating</p>
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
            value={rating}
          />
        </InputContainer> */}

        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Candidate</Button>
      </FormContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 450px;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Logo = styled.div`
  width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const FormContainer = styled.form`
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 55%;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;

  h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 33px;
    align-self: flex-start;

    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
`;

const InputContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;

  p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  input {
    width: 95%;
    height: 33px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin-top: 5px;

    &:hover {
      border: 1px solid orange;
    }
  }
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 70%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #f3b414;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;

export default Addcandidate;
```

Comment: can you add name on your input value please ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you will need to change this:

```
<Container>
      <Logo>
        <img src="./amazon_logo.png" alt="" />
      </Logo>

      <FormContainer >
        <h3>Add Candidate</h3>

        <InputContainer>
          <p>candidate_name</p>
          <input
            // type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.candidate_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>ImageURL</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.imageURL}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>party_name</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.party_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        {/* <InputContainer>
          <p>Rating</p>
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
            value={rating}
          />
        </InputContainer> */}

        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Candidate</Button>
      </FormContainer>
    </Container>
```

To this :

```
<Container>
      <Logo>
        <img src="./amazon_logo.png" alt="" />
      </Logo>

      <FormContainer >
        <h3>Add Candidate</h3>

        <InputContainer>
          <p>candidate_name</p>
          <input
            // type="text"
            name="my-name" <-- add this property -->
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.candidate_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>ImageURL</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.imageURL}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <p>party_name</p>
          <input
            name="my-name" <-- add this property -->
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data.party_name}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        {/* <InputContainer>
          <p>Rating</p>
          <input
            name="my-name" <-- add this property -->
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
            value={rating}
          />
        </InputContainer> */}

        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Candidate</Button>
      </FormContainer>
    </Container>
```